# SPSS or R: Determine the significant difference between levels within a category and between categories

Tags: r, statistics, spss, anova, tukey

I'm working with quite a small data and I previously used ANOVA and Tukey as post-hoc test when I had more data years before. Now, I actually forgot how to use SPSS but I have to use it for an old paper (but I can also use R).
My data have 4 Categories with 5 levels each except for the last category with just 2 levels. For each level, I have one numerical value (average of 3 raw data).

Sample data:

| Categories | Levels | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pH | 2 | .023 |
| pH | 3 | .032 |
| pH | 4 | .031 |
| pH | 5 | .000 |
| pH | 6 | .018 |
| Moisture | 10 | .032 |
| Moisture | 15 | .300 |
| Moisture | 20 | .185 |
| Moisture | 25 | .281 |
| Moisture | 30 | .100 |
| Light | With | .910 |
| Light | Without | .213 |

These are just sample data (I have 2 more categories). Are ANOVA and Tukey still applicable to my data? And how should I do this via SPSS or R?

I would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, anova and tukey is still applicable to the data.

To do it on spss or r, simply type;
spss dummy level 3 = pH(0.32).
For R, type; rdummy level 3 = pH(0.32).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried doing this in R by using this code (I tried using one category first and planned encoding the other values if it worked but it didn't):

`PC_ph <- data.frame(pH = c("2","3","4","5","6"), values = c("16.80790","12.71690","19.87151","26.18001","57.48847"))
PC_ph <- PC_ph %>%
     mutate(pH = as.factor(pH)) %>%
     mutate(PC = as.numeric(PC))
summary(aov(PC ~ pH, data = PC_ph))`

but the output I got was just -- Df Sum Sq Mean Sq

Can you suggest how I can do ANOVA and turkey here? Thank you.

Comment: You can do Anova and Tukey by finding a category with 1 level and having value of t2. The value of t2 is 0.010. Then we need to find the value of n, which obviously is 1 since for each level we have 1 numerical value. You can do the Anova considering the  with and without levels. For the tukey, the value of n can help to find b which can lead to finding the spss multiple category.

Comment: The value of t2 is 0.005.